# How to get the width of notification content extension?

Tags: ios, notifications, ios10, ios-app-extension

I have a notification content extension and I want to display an image in my `NotificationViewController`. I want to keep the width of the image the same as the controller's view and the aspect ratio of the image unchanged after scaling, so I need to calculate the height of the scaled image, which need the width of the controller's view. How to get the width of notification content extension?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just call `self.view.bounds.size.width` in `didReceiveNotification`. Because `viewDidLoad` is run first, then `viewWillAppear`, then `viewDidAppear`, last `didReceiveNotification`. However, you can not override `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get notification image width. You should add picture of maximum screen width's device. Operation system automatically resize image.